# Can I get the mouse position in OpenCV without a mouse event?

Tags: c++, opencv, callback, mouse

All the tutorials I find use `setMouseCallback()` to set a callback function to which the mouse position is passed. Unfortunately, this function is only called when an actual mouse event is occurring, but I'd like to get the mouse position while no keys on my mouse are pressed.

*Is that possible in OpenCV?*

Comment: `EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gga927593befdddc7e7013602bca9b079b0a8f2ec5fd35fe3f4b696518b146dcf675  seems a good start, isn't it?

Comment: @Miki it seems like that, but it's not. `EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` can be checked for, but that doesn't give me any information about the pointer position. This info is only passed to the callback function, which is not called unless one of the mousebuttons is pressed, held, or released.

Comment: It does work for me. If that's not what you need, please let me know ;).

Comment: You're absolutely correct, that works perfectly fine. My issue was that I didn't redraw when the mouse was moved, only when other mouse events occured. Dumb mistake, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` to get the position of the mouse:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void mouse_callback(int  event, int  x, int  y, int  flag, void *param)
{
    if (event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE) {
        cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b img(200, 200, Vec3b(0, 255, 0));

    namedWindow("example");
    setMouseCallback("example", mouse_callback);

    imshow("example", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```