# Is it possible to set cursor position from within OpenCV mouse events?

Tags: python, pynput

Is it possible to set/update the cursor coordinates from within OpenCV mouse events? I have a virtual keyboard and I am trying to make it such that whenever the cursor hovers over a button, it is locked at the mid-point of the button.

My current mouse callback function:

```
def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        global x1, y1
        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            x1, y1 = x, y
            for button in self.button_list:
                if button.is_hovered_over(x1, y1):
                    # set the cursor coordinates here
```

The main function:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()

from keyboards import QWERTYKeyboard
keyboard = QWERTYKeyboard.QWERTYKeyboard()

cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", keyboard.on_mouse)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    .
    .
    .
    pred_x, pred_y = model.predict(ave_x, ave_y)

    cv2.circle(image, (ave_x, ave_y), 1, (255, 0, 0), 5)

    mouse.position = (pred_x, pred_y)

    cv2.imshow("Image", image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
      break

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cap.release()
```

Comment: that's out of scope for OpenCV. that library is for computer vision, not for interfering with mouse and keyboard. you already know of `pynput`, so use it. do you have any issues with that? [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005809/can-i-get-the-mouse-position-in-opencv-without-a-mouse-event
this will help you

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-it-possible-to-set-cursor-position-from-within-opencv-mouse-events/11579